# 'Following' sites

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am a SharePoint admin, We got a issue where the user has followed a SharePoint site but when she tried to copy files from another site, the site she is following is not listed in the 'Following' sites. As a result she cannot copy content to it.

I have tried to unfollow the site and again followed but didn't work. Can you please help me how to proceed on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to follow the site. The user needs appropriate permission to upload content to the site being followed. Can you grant the user **Contribute** permission then try upload content again.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the points below:

1. Make sure you have proper permission with the followed site.
2. When did you follow the site? Make sure you wait enough time to update the following site list in SharePoint Online.
3. Check if the same issue occurred in other sites.